# Recommended signals to catch?

Tags: c, linux, posix

Currently, I catch SIGSEGV, send myself an email, and then abort() so I can get a core file and debug my program. (If I did not catch, there would be no way that I would not know that my particular program segfaulted. My program is run in a separate server from my own.)

Are there any other signals that I should catch for debugging or for reasons that I should know about ?

Comment: You absolutely should not catch SIGSEGV.

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that a SEGV hasn't *already* corrupted your program memory so much that an attempt to send email won't fail spectacularly?

You should follow division of responsibility practices and monitor your program from a totally *different* program.

Simply have a (very simple so it's far less likely to fail) program which checks to make sure your primary program is still running and, if not, send you that email. You can even do defence-in-depth and run two checkers, both of which check the primary program and each other.

If you're paranoid like me, you can even run them on separate machines :-)

Comment: Ok, since using signal.h is not guaranteed to work, how about this: 1.) remove signal.h from my program 2.) put setrlimit as the first line in my program so I can get a core 3.) use a shell script executed by a cronjob to check for core files and send me an email if there are

Comment: I thought, on Linux, SIGSEGV automatically gives you a core dump unless somebody has taken specific action to stop it from happening.  If that is the case, next time the program starts up, it could check its working directory for a core and then send the email out.  This, I think is the way most crash reporters work on OS X.

Comment: @JeremyP: SIGSEGV dumps core but cores are disabled by default on Linux distros so you have to use setrlimit to modify the soft limit (assuming that the hard limit is not zero or you would need root privileges).

Comment: @Jason:  Ok, it seems reasonable to use setrlimit as you suggest then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if your program attaches to a console, you might want to catch SIGINT to dump/flush any buffers/logs your are withholding.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not catch SIGSEGV / SIGBUS etc.

What you should do instead, is write a wrapper program which will detect if the subprocess exits from a signal, and identify the problem, then that process can carry out any required action.

If it is a server process, you probably also want to restart if it fails unexpectedly.