# Which "fatal" signals should a user-level program catch?

Tags: c, linux, signals, posix

First of all, [I do know that there was a similar question here in the past](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297062/recommended-signals-to-catch).

But that question wasn't answered properly. Instead, it diverted into suggestion what to do to catch signals.

So just to clarify: I've done whatever needs to be done to handle signals.
I have an application that forks a daemon that monitors the main process through pipe.
If a main process crashes (e.g. segmentation fault), it has a signal handler that writes all the required info to pipe and aborts.

The goal is to have as much info as possible *when something bad happens to the application*, w/o messing with "normal" operation, such as SIGHUP, SIGUSR1, etc.

So my question is: **which signals should I catch?**
I mean signals that w/o me catching them would cause application to abort anyway.

So far I've come up with the following list:

- SIGINT (^C, user-initiated, but still good to know)
- SIGTERM (`kill <pid>` from shell or, AFAIK, can be result of OutOfMemory)
- SIGSEGV
- SIGILL
- SIGFPE
- SIGBUS
- SIGQUIT

Does anybody know if I miss something? `kill -l` has lots of them... :)

Comment: So what kind of information are you already logging from your signal handlers? Which kind of information do like have logged additionally?

Comment: For instance, I get full backtrace and send it to the monitoring daemon through pipe, and then exit from the main process.

Comment: As mentioned as answer to the question you are linking, trying to do soemthing from a signal handler invoked due to receiving a `SIGSEGV` is rather vague thing to do.

Comment: @alk I know, and that's why I said that I've done whatever it needs to be done to do this. We can discuss this in details, but that's not the point of the question, and I don't want the discussion to divert from the main topic, *again*.

Comment: It really depends upon what kind of program you are coding. Some server programs providing very important services should worry much more than other programs about signaling. And the details are operating system specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm looking at my copy of advanced programming the unix environment (Stevens). According to the table in the section on signals, the following POSIX signals will by default terminate the process, if you don't catch them. It wouldn't be unreasonable to monitor all of these that you don't use:

- SIGABRT
- SIGALRM
- SIGFPE
- SIGHUP
- SIGILL
- SIGINT
- SIGKILL
- SIGPIPE
- SIGQUIT
- SIGSEGV
- SIGTERM
- SIGUSR1
- SIGUSR2

You can catch all of these except SIGKILL, but hopefully SIGKILL won't come up very often for you.

Note that your signal man page (`man 7 signal`) should give you the proper list for your system - this is the POSIX list, and may differ depending on your architecture.

Answer (score 5):

You should not catch the signal and write the code to a pipe. This is both unnecessary and not failsafe.

Let me quote an answer from the question you linked to, to point out why it's not failsafe: *"What makes you think that a SEGV hasn't already corrupted your program memory"*

Now you may be wondering how to do it better, and why I've said it is "unnecessary".

The return code of the `waitpid` syscall can be checked using `WIFSIGNALED()` to determine whether the process was terminated normally or via a signal, and `WTERMSIG()` will return the signal number.

This is failsafe *and* it does not require a handler or a pipe. Plus, you don't need to worry what to catch, because it will report *every* signal that terminates your process.

Comment: Agreed. And in the standard case no such "non user defined" signals are ever sent to process, as it is coded well und runs as it is itended to.

Comment: @Damon: `WIFSIGNALED()` - interesting, I probably missed this one in that question. However, it is very valuable to me to get as much info as possible, even if the function that handles SIGSEGV will crash because the heap was already corrupted. I still have the chance that it's not as corrupted as you think, and I'll get valuable info out. With just waiting for child to end, I won't get backtrace.

Comment: @kliteyn: [As much info as you probably need](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/core.5.html) is generated automatically, in a failsafe manner. Core is already the default disposition for `SIGSEGV`, `SIGILL`, `SIGABRT`, and `SIGFPE`. If that's not enough, you can set the disposition for any other signals you want accordingly, too.

Comment: @Damon: it's a portable application, that may also run on an embedded system that forbids dumping core files. So whatever info I can collect during the failure, is everything I have. Once the application has exited - that's it, moment is gone.

Answer (score 1):

It depends: whatever signal you like if that's useful to inform the user something bad just happened. However SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught.

Comment: "Whatever signal you like, that's very usefull to informthe user   something bad just happened"  - well, that's kinda the point of the question. Which signals are relevant? I mean only "fatal" signals that would have caused the application to abort.

Comment: Your application shall not abort unexpectedly.

Comment: @alk: OK, I'll add it to my to-do list :-)