# PHP SIGTERM in CLI

Tags: php, command-line-interface, sigterm

I'm running php scripts from CLI, and i'd like to execute a function when script stopped with ctrl + c. I tried this:

```
<?php

declare(ticks = 1);

function sigint() {
    echo 'This is the end';
    exit;
}

pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, 'sigint');

$i = 1;

do {

    echo $i++ . ' ';

    sleep(1);

} while (TRUE);
```

but it doesn't works. How can i do this?

Comment: use SIGINT instead of SIGTERM

Comment: @nadir OP want to accept it as an answer. Please, make it as an answer. Thannk you.

Answer (score 1):

When attaching the handler in `pcntl_signal`, use `SIGINT` instead of `SIGTERM`

Comment: It might be safer to attach handlers for both signals. [Related question about which signals are fatal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219071/which-fatal-signals-should-a-user-level-program-catch)

Comment: Well, depends on what OP wants to achieve. If he only wants to handle Ctrl-c, it is enough.